# Cypress not able to read password from GitHub secrets but it is able to get record key

Tags: continuous-integration, cypress, github-actions, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

Here is my .yml file

```yaml
name: smoke tests`enter code here`
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  cypress-test:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install cypress and verify
        run: npm install
      - name: Run smoke tests
        env:
          CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY: ${{ secrets.CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY }}
          CYPRESS_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.CYPRESS_PASSWORD }}
        run: npx cypress-ntlm run -e TAGS='@smoke',configFile=test --spec 'cypress/integration/cucumber-tests/**/*.feature'
```

Comment: Same result even after trying `CYPRESS_password: ${{ secrets.CYPRESS_PASSWORD }}`? Some stacktrack can help.

Comment: I was able to get password from GitHub secrets using 
npx cypress-ntlm run -e TAGS='@smoke',configFile=test CYPRESS_PASSWORD=$CYPRESS_PASSWORD --spec 'cypress/integration/cucumber-tests/**/*.feature'

Comment: You can add that as an answer so in the future someone perhaps could refer to it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get password from GitHub secrets using npx cypress-ntlm run -e TAGS='@smoke',configFile=test CYPRESS_PASSWORD=$CYPRESS_PASSWORD --spec 'cypress/integration/cucumber-tests/**/*.feature'